# How to position two bootstrap navbar at top on scroll (sticky-top) without overlapping?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I used 2 navbar set to top on scroll using bootstrap 4 sticky-top class. But the problem is 2nd one goes up (overlap) over the 1st one when I scroll and that is why I can not see the 1st one. 2nd One should be placed bellow of the 1st one on scroll. Is there any way to do that?
Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body style="height:1500px">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <br>
  <h3>Sticky Navbar</h3>
  <p>A sticky navigation bar stays fixed at the top of the page when you scroll past it.</p>
  <p>Scroll this page to see the effect. <strong>Note:</strong> sticky-top does not work in IE11 and earlier.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid"><br>
  <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
  <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
  <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
  <p>Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text. Some example text.</p>
</div>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top sticky-top-2">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo 2</a>
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in bootstrap css, you will find codes like bellow

```
@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
  .sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1020;
  }
}
```

for the 2nd navbar, you can copy the code and paste in additional css or custom css and paste with renaming the class like **.sticky-top-2** and set the **top: 100px** or the height value you set for the 1st navbar and then if you want first navbar should drop down over the 2nd navbar just set the z-index value less then the 1020 like z-index: 1019; So, the final code like

```
@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
  .sticky-top2 {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 1019;
  }
}
```

Now change the HTML code where 2nd navbar has the call of **.sticky-top** to **

> .sticky-top2

**

Comment: Yes, it is what I wanted. Thanks both of you @Setu and Kuci

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both of them have top: 0; The second navbar must be moved away from the height of the first one.

If you want more detailed help, put in the code

Comment: Here is the full code 

https://codepen.io/Software_ss/pen/rNjPzRE